# what is faster? Looping through list or string?

Tags: python-3.x, performance

I need to remove duplicates from a large list of numbers, but keep the order the same. I thought this would be an effective way of dealing with it:

```
def rmDuplicate(unsorted):
unique = []

for item in unsorted:
    if item not in unique:
        unique.append(item)

return unique
```

But then I realised it could also be done in a string, where you would just paste all the non-duplicates after each other and split them afterwards, or seperate them by comma's. Would there be any difference in speed between these 2 methods, and if so, which is the fastest? Or would there be an even faster way, if your list is really long.

Comment: Rather than speculate, you could use the `timeit` module and see for yourself. Note that string concatenation is more expensive than list appending (since strings are immutable). In fact, a basic optimization in Python is to build up large strings by creating lists of strings and only joining them in the end. Thus I am skeptical that it would be a good idea to replace list appending by string concatenation.